# Linux workstation monitoring tools

Tags: linux, opensuse, monitoring, upgrade

I am currently working in a company that runs Linux (openSUSE 12.1) on the workstations (about 200 computers).

I am looking for a tool or methods that could allow me to monitor them remotely, upgrade the system for all of them.
I was thinking creating my own repository and then allow the computers to upgrade themselves through it.

Does anyone work with these kind of tools ? Or could share his/her experience?

Comment: You mean monitoring or remotely manage? By monitoring I mean, check or record resources usage or applications status. By manage I mean remotely run commands or give any kind of assistance.

Comment: Check nagios for monitoring and puppet for configuration management. http://www.nagios.org/ and https://puppetlabs.com/

Comment: @ghm1014 I mean run commands

Comment: For updating I would say Yast must have it's way to create a LAN repo and update automatically. For running commands just SSH with non-password authentication isn't enough?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [OMD](http://omdistro.org/) (Open Monitoring Distribution) in order to monitor your computers. OMD can be installed very easily and it is very powerful. Furthermore, the system requirements on your monitored computers are very low. Check it out on [mathias-kettner.de](http://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk_demo.html).

At least you should have a look at the graphs of the performance data.

A quote from the OMD-Wiki:

> OMD currently comes with the following software:
>
> - nagios
>
>   - nagios-plugins
>   - nsca
>   - check_nrpe
> - Icinga
> - Shinken
> - nagvis
> - pnp4nagios
> - rrdtool/rrdcached
> - Check_MK
> - MK Livestatus
> - Multisite
> - dokuwiki

Answer (score 0):

Check the eginnovations performance monitoring, reporting tool for Linux and other operating systems - http://www.eginnovations.com/web/linux-server-monitoring.htm

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [SeaLion](https://sealion.com/) a try. It is very easy to install and operate. The graphs are detailed yet simple to understand. The alerting feature is useful and responsive. Plus there is a daily digest feature which sends you an email with the summary of your servers' performance that day. It's the simplest yet most useful solution I found to keep an eye on my servers. Hope it might work for you as well.